# How to create a directional lighting effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to mimic the lighting effect applied to the object in the first photo into the 2<sup>nd</sup> photo in Photoshop.

I've tried using gradients and inner shadow with no success.

Notice the lighting effect is brighter on top and darker on bottom, I'm unsure how to create this type of lighting effect?

**Effect I'm looking for**

[image: Trying To Match This]

**As far as I've gotten**

[image: Apply similar lighting onto this picture]

Comment: You have to manually paint them in since there is no 3D info for the computer to do this for you.

Comment: If you're familiar with any 3D software, you could create a geometric approximation of the object (or just the relevant surface), add lighting to get what you're after, and bring a grayscale render into Photoshop with the Luminosity blending mode selected for the layer.

Answer (score 0):

You seemingly have already clipped the background apart and treated it separately. That's OK. Keep different things in different layers to keep the task manageable.

You can insert one or more curves adjustment layers which have layer masks to focus the effect only to the area where that curve fits. I inserted only one to show the idea. One can paint black and white directly to the mask. I put there a gradient and then painted manually some white more.

[image]

If you have say 3 different curves with different layer masks making light and shadow to the machine you can either lift the background above them or more preferably keep the machine and its adjustment layers in a group which has blending mode Normal. That keeps all adjustments inside the group.

The background and its own adjustment layers can have the same.